# How to simulate real world Active Directory problems with test DCs in a VM environment

Tags: windows, active-directory

I currently have 3 DC's on a Windows 2012R2 server all replicating fine. 
I also have an exchange VM and 2 client Win7 VMs joined to the domain.  All just for testing, training purposes.

What is the best way to simulate replication problems , KDC trust issues, DC tombstoning, RPC, principle name errors, etc as "naturally" as possible.
I realize I can just either remove the DC's by deleting objects, removing DNS zones, etc but I would really like to do this as close to "real world" as possible.

Are there online labs, or guides on how to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

delete the SPNS on your dc, delete dns records,  that'll be fun, or power them all down and wait 6 months